# Baggage Allowance on connecting Delta Airlines flight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, check-in

I am planning to book an international flight from Ahmedabad, India to Pittsburgh, US in the second week of August 2021. My planned itinerary is (not yet booked):

Air India 532: Ahmedabad to New Delhi

Air India 101: New Delhi to New York

Delta 5781: New York to Pittsburgh

I had a few questions regarding the Delta flight in this itinerary:

1. On the baggage policy, it is written that 2 pieces of check-in baggage will be allowed, while there is no information for the cabin baggage. I contacted Air India and they are giving me 2 pieces with 23 kg each (total 46 kg) for the first two flights in my itinerary. Can you please tell me the cabin and check-in baggage allowance for the flight Delta 5781 (in my planned itinerary above) in kilograms?
2. For the connecting flight Delta 5781 in my planned itinerary above, will I have to collect my luggage and check-in again for that flight, or will it be sufficient to check-in at Ahmedabad only and receive my luggage finally at Pittsburgh?
3. Air India is offering me an additional 23 kg of baggage because of my international student visa. Will the Delta Airlines flight on my itinerary offer a similar extra baggage allowance for students?

I would be grateful if you could help me out with my questions.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends a lot on whether this a is a single ticket or two separate tickets. Even if it' a single ticket, it depends which carrier issues the ticket. In general, for a single ticket, whatever conditions for checked baggage the ticket states apply to the entire flight.

Since Air India is Star Alliance, doesn't code share with Delta, and doesn't even offer Pittsburgh as a destination, this may be two separate tickets. In this case I would recommend to have at least 5 hours in JFK between the flights.

> Can you please tell me the cabin and check-in baggage allowance for the flight Delta 5781 (in my planned itinerary above) in kilograms?

That depends highly on the class of service and how the ticket was booked. Check in allowance varies between no bags and two free bags up to 32kg each. For a separate economy ticket, the most "common" would be: bags are restricted to 23 kg, first one costs $30, second one costs $40 (per leg). If it's a single ticket, chances are you have two free bags up to 23 kg. You can check here https://www.delta.com/us/en/baggage/overview

Cabin luggage for Delta is normal: "one carry + one personal item". They don't check weight or size unless it's obviously wrong. If it fits, it fits.

> For the connecting flight Delta 5781 in my planned itinerary above, will I have to collect my luggage and check-in again for that flight

Yes. You ALWAYS need to collect luggage and clear immigration at your first port of entry in the US. If it's a single ticket, you can drop the bags directly after customs at the "recheck" or "connecting flights". If it's two separate tickets, you need to go to the Delta check in kiosk and check your bags there. That's also where you would pay the bag charges.

> Air India is offering me an additional 23 kg of baggage because of my international student visa. Will the Delta Airlines flight on my itinerary offer a similar extra baggage allowance for students?

Sorry, no idea. Certainly not if it's two separate tickets.

Comment: Whilst they don't codeshare, Air India does interlink with Delta, and they do sell tickets from India to PIT with the connection being to DL in NYC/JFK, so it is most likely one ticket.